# stopping condition on gradient value tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I would like to implement a stopping condition based on the value of the gradient of the loss function w.r.t. the weights.
For example, let's say I have something like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(a_loss_function)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

then I would like to run the graph with something like this:

```
for step in range(TotSteps):
    output = sess.run([input], feed_dict=some_dict)
    if(grad_taken_in_some_way < some_treshold):
        print("Training finished.")
        break
```

I am not sure what I should pass to sess.run() in order to get as output also the gradient (besides all other stuff I need). I am not even sure whether this is the correct approach or I should do it differently. I made some tries but I failed every time. Hope someone has some hints.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: English correction

EDIT2: Answer by **Iballes** is exactly what I wanted to do. Still, I am not sure how to norm and sum all the gradients. Since I have different layer in my CNN and different weights with different shape, if I just do what you suggested, I get an error on the add_n() operation (since I am trying to add together matrices with different shapes). So probably I should do something like:

```
grad_norms = [tf.nn.l2_normalize(g[0], 0) for g in grads_and_vars]      
grad_norm = [tf.reduce_sum(grads) for grads in grad_norms]
final_grad = tf.reduce_sum(grad_norm)
```

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line `output = sess.run([input], feed_dict=some_dict)` makes think that you have a little misunderstanding of the `sess.run` command. What you call `[input]` is supposed to be a list of tensors that are to be fetched by the `sess.run` command. Hence, it is an output rather than an input. To tackle your question, let's assume that you are doing something like `output = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=some_dict)` instead (in order to monitor the training loss).

Also, I suppose you want to formulate your stopping criterion using the *norm* of the gradient (the gradient itself is a multi-dimensional quantity). Hence, what you want to do is to fetch the norm of the gradient each time you execute the graph. To that end, you have to do two things. 1) Add the gradient norm to the computation graph. 2) Fetch it in each call to `sess.run` in your training loop.

Ad 1) You have added the gradients to the graph via

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(a_loss_function)
```

and now have the tensors holding the gradients in `grads_and_vars` (one for each trained variable in the graph). Let's take the norm of each gradient and then sum it up:

```
grad_norms = [tf.nn.l2_loss(g) for g, v in grads_and_vars]
grad_norm = tf.add_n(grad_norms)
```

There you have your gradient norm.

Ad 2) Inside your loop, fetch the gradient norm alongside the loss by telling the `sess.run` command to do so.

```
for step in range(TotSteps):
    l, gn = sess.run([loss, grad_norm], feed_dict=some_dict)
    if(gn < some_treshold):
        print("Training finished.")
        break
```

Comment: Any thoughts on that answer @AndreaPavone?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do. Still, I am not sure how to norm and sum all the gradients. Since I have different layer in my CNN and different weights with different shape, if I just do what you suggested, I get an error on the add_n() operation (since I am trying to add together matrices with different shapes). More details in the edited questions. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I got confused with tensorflow function names. What I wanted to do is ``grad_norms = [tf.nn.l2_loss(g) for g, v in grads_and_vars]``. My original answer used a function ``tf.nn.l2_norm``, which does not exist and I did **not** mean ``tf.nn.l2_normalize``. The function ``tf.nn.l2_loss`` takes the squared L2 norm of a vector and, hence, produces a scalar regardless of the dimensions of that tensor. These scalars can then be added together to compute the L2 norm of the overall gradient. (Corrected it in the answer.)